# Unable to schedule notifications

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

Unable to schedule notification for multiple times for different times , 
the notifications which are getting scheduled are the last undated timing only the below code contains two methods which has their own alarm manager but still even though two notifications are scheduled only one appears and that whould be scheduled in the last

```
public void monday_sch(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 30000, intent, 0);
        String stat=smonday.getText().toString();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date d1 = null;
            d1 = format.parse(stat);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(d1);
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);
            String  oneHourBack = String.valueOf(cal.getTime());
            String customiese=oneHourBack.substring(10, oneHourBack.length() - 18);
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),customiese,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(customiese.trim(), ":");
            hour_mon = Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken());
            min_mon = Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken());

        }catch (Exception kk){

        }
        if(monday==true)
        {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,6);

            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour_mon);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min_mon);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            alarmManager_mon = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        /*alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (i * 1000), (i * 1000), pendingIntent);*/
            alarmManager_mon.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);

        }
        else if(monday==false){
            alarmManager_mon = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager_mon.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    }
    public void sunday_sch(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 30000, intent, 0);
        String stat=ssunday.getText().toString();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date d1 = null;
            d1 = format.parse(stat);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(d1);
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);
            String  oneHourBack = String.valueOf(cal.getTime());
            String customiese=oneHourBack.substring(10, oneHourBack.length() - 18);
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),customiese,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(customiese.trim(), ":");
            hour_sun = Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken());
            min_sun = Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken());

        }catch (Exception kk){}
        if(sunday==true)
        {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,6);

            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour_sun);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min_sun);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            alarmManager_sun = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        /*alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (i * 1000), (i * 1000), pendingIntent);*/
            alarmManager_sun.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);



        }
        else if(sunday==false){
            alarmManager_sun = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager_sun.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    }


`
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set schedule notification for multiple times for different times
then use: `PendingIntent unique_id`

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), unique_id, intent, 0);
```

`unique_id` is set different every time.